# Return from lambdas or Kotlin: 'return' is not allowed here

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to write function which will tell me that string is nice, nice means string has at least one repetition of letters in the string. But I can't to make return from lambda, it's always return false, though condition in if statement passed. Can somebody explain me how make return?

I have tried to write return, but IDEA gave me the message **Kotlin: 'return' is not allowed here**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("sddfsdf".isNice())
}

fun String.isNice(): Boolean {
    val hasRepeat = {
        for (i in 0 .. (length - 2)) {
            if (subSequence(i, i + 2).toSet().size == 1) {
                true
                println(subSequence(i, i + 2))
            }
        }
        false
    }

    return hasRepeat()
}
```

ouput is:

```
dd
false
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can label lambda and then use labeled return:

```
fun String.isNice(): Boolean {
    val hasRepeat = hasRepeat@ {
        for (i in 0 .. (length - 2)) {
            if (subSequence(i, i + 2).toSet().size == 1) {
                return@hasRepeat true
                println(subSequence(i, i + 2)) // <-- note that this line is unreachable
            }
        }
        false
    }

    return hasRepeat()
}
```

or you can use named local function, if you do not need `hasRepeat` to be function reference:

```
fun String.isNice(): Boolean {
    fun hasRepeat(): Boolean {
        for (i in 0 .. (length - 2)) {
            if (subSequence(i, i + 2).toSet().size == 1) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    return hasRepeat()
}
```

Answer (score 20):

You cannot do a [non-local return](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns) inside a lambda but you can change your lambda to an anonymous function:

```
fun String.isNice(): Boolean {
    val hasRepeat = fun(): Boolean {
        for (i in 0..(length - 2)) {
            if (subSequence(i, i + 2).toSet().size == 1) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    return hasRepeat()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's just example, I know, that I can place this function on isNice() level, anyway thanks.

Comment: Got it. I've updated my answer to remove the unnecessary simplified example.