# How to return from Kotlin function type

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using function type to store code to be invoked on button click.
How to return from this function type
Code given below :

```
var SearchClickEvent: ((searchString: String) -> Unit)? = null

inputDialog!!.SearchClickEvent = Search_Click  

private val Search_Click = { searchString: String ->
    if(searchString.isEmpty()){
        return//Error msg : return is not allowed here  
        //How to return from here
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I'm storing a piece of code in a variable not calling or writing any function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return from lambdas or Kotlin: 'return' is not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798269/return-from-lambdas-or-kotlin-return-is-not-allowed-here)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to create a [label](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) with explicit return statement in lambda, for example:

```
//   label for lambda---v
val Search_Click = action@{ searchString: String ->
    if (searchString.isEmpty()) {
        return@action;
    }
    // do working
}
```

**OR** invert the if statement as below:

```
val Search_Click = { searchString: String ->
    if (!searchString.isEmpty()) {
      // do working
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like this:

```
private val Search_Click =
    fun(searchString: String) {
        if (searchString.isEmpty()) return
        // more code
    }
```

*Kotlin in Action:*

> If you use the `return` keyword in a lambda, it returns from the
>   function in which you called the lambda, not just from the lambda
>   itself. Such a `return` statement is called a **non-local return**, because
>   it returns from a larger block than the block containing the `return`
>   statement.
>
> The rule is simple: `return` returns from the closest function
>   declared using the `fun` keyword. Lambda expressions don’t use the
>   `fun` keyword, so a `return` in a lambda returns from the outer
>   function.