# How to early return for a function that has a return type of Unit?

Tags: kotlin

If I have a function that has a signature to return "Unit", I am not able to early return. Is there a workaround?

```
var f: () -> Unit
        f = {
            if (false) {
                return // compiler error: "return" is not allowed here
            }
            "whatever"
        }
```

Comment: Looks like nothing related to unit [Return from lambdas or Kotlin: 'return' is not allowed here - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798269/return-from-lambdas-or-kotlin-return-is-not-allowed-here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not related to the return type which is `Unit` in your case. You need to use labels in order to return from a lambda:

```kotlin
var f: () -> Unit
f = myLabel@{
    if (false) {
        return@myLabel
    }
    "whatever"
}
```

Comment: I encountered this issue in jetpack compose and the compiler asked me to add the label (it works). OutlinedTextField(
                onValueChange = { value ->
                    if (needEarlyReturn) { return@OutlinedTextField }) ...) Do you know where does that @OutlinedTextField come from? I cannot find the label in OutlinedTextField.kt.